# How to instantiate different classes in a loop?

Tags: python, class

I wrote:

```
atomic_labels = ["xWant", "oWant", "xAttr", "xNeed", "xIntent", "xEffect", "xReact", "oReact", "oEffect"]

for label in atomic_labels:
    PROCESSORS["atomic_" + label.lower()] = lambda: AtomicProcessor([label, "other"])
```

However, it seems that it initalized all classes with the last label (`[oEffect, other]`)

Comment: Why do you need a `lambda:`?

Comment: You need to capture the `label` each time: `lambda label=label: AtomicProcessor([label, "other"]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer if not I get `TypeError: 'AtomicProcessor' object is not callable
`

Comment: Then that is a separate issue. You've not shown `AtomicProcessor` class/function

Comment: @quamrana thanks, it was resolved.

Comment: This would make `PROCESSORS` a dictionary of functions, not list of classes, by the way

Comment: i.e. - I dont see why the lambda is needed - https://ideone.com/v3nFI2

Comment: @OneCricketeer my problem was solved, but if you want to know about the class, its the link https://github.com/puraminy/pet/blob/9c5a3f2e2c35d7d11e12ac6e6ee790443d4d75ae/pet/tasks.py#L767

Comment: Yup, again, you don't need a lambda if you actually want a _list of classes_ like your question title stated